# How to replace NA in a dataframe for a specific value using the results of another column and taking into account conditions of another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

I have a `dataframe` composed of 9 columns with more than 4000 observations. For this question I will present a simpler `dataframe` (I use the `tidyverse` library)

Let's say I have the following `dataframe`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Product = c("Bread","Oranges","Eggs","Bananas","Whole Bread" ),
             Weight = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
             Units = c(2,6,1,2,1),
             Price = c(1,3.5,0.5,0.75,1.5))
df
```

I want to replace the `NA` values of the `Weight` column for a number multiplied by the results of `Units` depending on the word showed by the column `Product`. Basically, is a rule like:

> Replace NA in Weight for 2.5*number of units if Product contains the word "Bread". Replace for 1 if Product contains the word "Eggs"

The thing is that I don't know how to code somehting like that in `R`. I tried the following code that a kind user gave me for a similar question:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(Weight = case_when(Product == "bread" & is.na(Weight) ~ 0.25*Units))
```

But it doesn't work and it doesn't take into account the fact that if there is `"Whole Bread"` written in my `dataframe` it also has to apply the rule.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of them are not exact matches, so use `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(Weight = case_when(is.na(Weight) & 
     str_detect(Product, regex("Bread", ignore_case = TRUE)) ~ 2.5 * Units, 
     is.na(Weight) & Product == "Eggs"~ Units, TRUE ~ Weight))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Product     Weight Units Price
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Bread          5       2  1   
2 Oranges        1       6  3.5 
3 Eggs           1       1  0.5 
4 Bananas       NA       2  0.75
5 Whole Bread    2.5     1  1.5
```

Comment: Very useful answer. I still get a message error:  
>Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Poids = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `2.5 * Unites`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
I tried to correct it by doing: 
`df <- df %>% 
  mutate(as.numeric(Weight),
         as.numeric(Units),
         as.numeric(Price))`
But I still get the error message

Comment: @MatiasV. that is an issue when you have a non-numeric column.  Check the `class(df$Units)`

Comment: @MatiasV. your example shows numeric column.  Try to convert `df$Units <- as.numeric(df$Units)` before doing

Comment: It's solved! As a matter of fact I had to convert the data to numeric individually. I'm very grateful